# Restrict maximim permitted request and response time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timeout, rack

Is it possible within the Rails app (in Rack?) to restrict the maximum permitted duration for https requests and responses? Like a forced timeout.

Long running http post requests can be considered a vulnerability to a DoS attack.

Rails 5.2.3, Ruby 2.6.5

The app is hosted on AWS, in Elastic Beanstalk with an Application Load Balancer (ALB). I thought configuring this within the Rails app (for production) would be cleanest if possible, but otherwise wherever it can be done - ALB, puma etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think it's possible in Rails.

Check out https://github.com/sharpstone/rack-timeout. Also can restrict Puma [worker_timeout](https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/636732c44774a3dc49474f3fb0627fb3a6aaafb3/lib/puma/dsl.rb#L604) (tho explicitly mentions does not protect against slow requests, but see: https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/1024).

Definitely available as a configuration in ALB!

Comment: Thanks, any hints how to configure in ALB? Is it via AWS Shield? or WAF?

Comment: ALB configuration: `idle_timeout.timeout_seconds`. The idle timeout value, in seconds. The default is 60 seconds. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/application-load-balancers.html.

Comment: idle timeout is an unused connection timeout not a request timeout though, right @avimoondra ?